# React JS - How do I pass variables (parameters) to the API URL?

Tags: json, reactjs, api, url-parameters

I have a single page that consist of two dropdown-list components; The page is only accessible upon successful authentication (valid token). Both dropdown-list consumes it's data from different JSON-API's. I have one of the dropdown list functional, but for the other, the URL to it's API requires parameters.

**Example URL**:
http://buildingsAPI:111/api/buildings/

**tested via postman with an id appended**: 
http://buildingsAPI:111/api/buildings/abcde-abce-abc2-111-2222

sample Json:

```
[
    {
        "abc_buildingid": "1111-2222-3333-aaa-1111117",
        "abc_energyprogramid": "abcde-abce-abc2-111-2222",
        "siteName": "Building 1",
        "Available": false,
        "clientName": "Client 1"
    },
    {
        "abc_buildingid": "222-2222-3333-aaa-1111117",
        "abc_energyprogramid": "xyz11-abce-abc2-111-2222",
        "siteName": "Building 2",
        "Available": false,
        "clientName": "Client 2"
    },
]
```

...am already obtaining the token upon user authentication (localStorage), but I also need to append/pass the abc_energyprogramid as a parameter to the API URL.

...**the code**:

```
     constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.getToken = this.getToken.bind(this);
    }


componentDidMount() {
    const bearerToken = this.getToken();

    fetch('http://buildingsAPI:111/api/buildings/?myparam1={abc_energyprogramid}', {
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${bearerToken}`
              },
        })
        .then(results => results.json())
        .then(buildings => this.setState({ buildings: buildings }))
      }

    getToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.buildings);
        return(
            <div>
            <select className="custom-select" id="siteName">
                    { this.state.buildings.map(item =>(
                    <option key={item.siteName}>{item.siteName}</option>
                    ))
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

...I currently get an error:" Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError):unexpected end of JSON input" on this line of the code: .then(results => results.json()). Could I get some help with this please?

Comment: I think your problem is not here but with your backend. Check whether it is returning proper json in response header and response body.

Comment: Your json looks more like an array, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: abc_energyprogramid is part of the object, (as a string) in the JSON file.  {abc_energyprogramid} ...would this be the correct way to pass it?

Comment: @Anas - it is an array, the other API am consuming  for the client has the same setup, and the code works, but for the buildings, that API requires a parameter at the end; that is the only difference between the two API's being consumed

Comment: @user1724708 try this
`const param = 'abc_energyprogramid'`
const a = `http://buildingsAPI:111/api/buildings/?myparam1=${param}` Use back ticks from start and the end of the variable a value.. can't do it here it's being treated as a code

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you're referencing `abc_energyprogramid`

Change this:

```
fetch('http://buildingsAPI:111/api/buildings/?myparam1={abc_energyprogramid}')
```

to:

```
fetch(`http://buildingsAPI:111/api/buildings/?myparam1=${abc_energyprogramid}`)
```

Notice the back-ticks and ES6 template string literal.

Comment: How can I do the same thing using Axios?